# Rails get objects in front of dot of a class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
students = Student.limit(3)
students.approve()

def self.approve
    # ...
end
```

I want to get students and use each_with_index, but it fails.
I tried self, it points out

```
"NoMethodError: undefined method `each_with_index' for #<Class:0x00000007a1b920>".
```

I just want the objects in front of my method, how can I do this, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `approve` method you have an ActiveRecord::Relation, but you need an array instead:

```
def self.approve_all
  all.each_with_index do |user, index|
    ...
  end
end
```

Class methods in ActiveRecord models can be called not only on the class itself, but also on ActiveRecord::Relation objects.

So for example, we can call the `.approve_all` method not only directly on the class: `Student.approve_all`, but also on any relation for the `Student` class: `Student.order(name: :asc).limit(10).where(state: "not_approved").approve_all`

But i think the method should be at least named `update_all`, and i would try to figure out a better solution for this problem.

Comment: `all` in this case is called on the relation, which is in this case `limit(3)`. Try reading some docs before downvoting the next time

Comment: In the ActiveRecord model class methods can be also called on the current relation, to allow chaining

Comment: Feel free to point me in the right direction and link a source explaining your mentioned functionality. I couldn't find anything mentioning that.

Comment: You can start with reading this article for example: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/

Comment: I've tested this functionality and all does refer to the relation just as you said. Always figured that since self methods are class methods they should  have parameters passed to them and be separated from instance methods. This is a nice functionality to know, thank you. If you update your answer with the explanation I will upvote.